# MouseEvent click gets RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to dispatch event click on a tag element in the DOM and I'm getting:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

How can I solve this?

I tried using the event.stopPropagation(), but itdidn't work:

```
var shareButton = document.querySelectorAll('.shrer');

for (var i = 0; i < shareButton.length; i++) {
    shareButton[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        var thisClass = this.className;
        sharer(thisClass)
    })
}

function sharer(shareWith) {
    var jobLink = window.location;
    var subject = document.querySelectorAll('.titleWrap h2')[0].innerHTML;
    var textBody = 'a job for you text';

    if (shareWith.match(/MailShare/)) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(shareWith)[0].href= 'mailto:?subject=' +subject+ '&body=' +textBody+  '%0D%0A' +jobLink+ '';
        document.getElementsByClassName(shareWith)[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: false, cancelable: true, view: window}));
    } 

}
```

Comment: You're calling `sharer` when click on a button having class `shrer`, `sharer` function clicks the button having class `shrer`, which again calls `sharer` ... --> basicly an infinite loop which is stopped by the error. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Teemu, ok after i read you comment again i understand my mistake, i made the mouse event click on it again and again... :) i fix it by adding document.location.href instead of the click mouse-event

Answer (score 0):

fixed by using document.location.href

```
function sharer(shareWith) {
    var jobLink = window.location;
    var subject = document.querySelectorAll('.titleWrap h2')[0].innerHTML;
    var textBody = 'a job for you text';

    if (shareWith.match(/MailShare/)) {
        var mailto = 'mailto:?subject=' +subject+ '&body=' +textBody+  '%0D%0A' +jobLink+ '';
        document.location.href = mailto;
    } 

}
```